# Make menu bootstrap compatible

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with my WordPress nav menu. It is currently looking like this : [image: Wordpress Problem]

I am trying to make my bootstrap 3.3.7 (think that's the right version) menu work and that is the error. The line of code i am using is:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme-location' => 'main_menu' ) ); ?>
```

and my `functions.php` has this code:

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main_menu'   => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
      'footer_menu' => __('Footer Menu')
    );
  )
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

I have read that the problem can be solved with walkernav but when trying to use it, it does not work any help?

EDIT: My Header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php  coldstar_the_page_link( 'front-page.php' );  ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/companylogo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-md" alt="Bed Centre Grimsby Logo">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="top-contact hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <li class="phone">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          01472 267660
        </li>
        <li class="email">
          <span class="icon"></span> <a href="mailto:sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk">sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk</a>
        </li>
        <li class="facebook">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Bedcentregrimsby/" target="_blank"><img src="http://beta.bedcentregrimsby.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bedcentregrimsby/assets/images/facebook-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'  => 'primary',
            'depth'           => 1,   // 1 = with dropdowns, 0 = no dropdowns.
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
            'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
          ) );
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   <!-- END container -->
</nav>
<div class="feature-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 delivery">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>FREE Local Delivery<span>We deliver for FREE within a distance of 8 miles.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 parking">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <p>FREE Parking<span>Our carpark is free for our customers.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 disability">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <p>Wheelchair Friendly<span>Our store is accessible for wheelchairs. </span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT2: This is how it should perform in html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>


            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php  coldstar_the_page_link( 'front-page.php' );  ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/companylogo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-md" alt="Bed Centre Grimsby Logo">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="top-contact hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <li class="phone">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    01472 267660
                </li>
                <li class="email">
                    <span class="icon"></span> <a href="mailto:sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk">sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk</a>
                </li>
                <li class="facebook">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Bedcentregrimsby/" target="_blank"><img src="http://beta.bedcentregrimsby.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bedcentregrimsby/assets/images/facebook-logo.png"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="current"><a href="localhost:81">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Products</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bedsteads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/bed-guide">Bed Guide</a></li>
                <li><a href="/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>



    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does not work what? Do you use the specialized [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) which does exactly what you need?

Comment: I think my issue is I'm not sure how to implement it, I've looked on the documentation but still struggling.

Comment: Are you sure you have closed all the Php `<?php  ?>` tags?

Comment: Yes I have made sure I have

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: my own basic underscores theme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap drop down menu with wp\_nav\_menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88604/bootstrap-drop-down-menu-with-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: I could send you my walker-nav.php i'm basically porting from bootstrap to WordPress

Comment: You will need a custom Walker_Nav_Menu, take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313541/135157)

Comment: had a look but it'ss does not seem to work

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and how did you load it?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: From [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking): Bootstrap still requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but you’re advised to use version 3.x since v3.x’s supported browsers are the ones Bootstrap supports plus v3.x has some security fixes.

Comment: Do you already have an idea of how the menu in html should be?

Comment: I have the menu all done in html and css just the conversion to header.php

Comment: I added the closing tag of the div container (it's peer reviewed)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php coldstar_the_page_link( 'front-page.php' ); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/companylogo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-md" alt="Bed Centre Grimsby Logo">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="top-contact hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <li class="phone">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          01472 267660
        </li>
        <li class="email">
          <span class="icon"></span> <a href="mailto:sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk">sales@bedcentregrimsby.co.uk</a>
        </li>
        <li class="facebook">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Bedcentregrimsby/" target="_blank"><img src="http://beta.bedcentregrimsby.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bedcentregrimsby/assets/images/facebook-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
              'container'      => false,
              'menu_id'        => 'joey-ireland',
              'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
              'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
              'theme_location' => 'primary',  // must match in register_nav_menus
              'depth'          => 5,
              'fallback_cb'    => false,
              'walker'         => new Joey_Bootstrap_Walker(),
          ));

class Joey_Bootstrap_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $has_child = false;
        if ( $args->walker->has_children !== false ) {
            $has_child = true;
        }

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );

        // Check our custom has_children property.
        $class_drop = '';
        if ( $has_child ) {
            $class_drop = $class_names !== '' ? ' dropdown' : 'dropdown';
        }

        if ( $class_names ) {
          $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . $class_drop . '"';
        } else {
          $class_names = $class_drop !== '' ? ' class="' . $class_drop . '"' : '';
        }

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        if ( $has_child === true ) {
            $attributes .= ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"';
        }

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
  ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="feature-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 delivery">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>FREE Local Delivery<span>We deliver for FREE within a distance of 8 miles.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 parking">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <p>FREE Parking<span>Our carpark is free for our customers.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 disability">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <p>Wheelchair Friendly<span>Our store is accessible for wheelchairs. </span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For documentation, see here:

- [register_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)  -  *Registers a single custom Navigation Menu in the custom menu editor*

---

- [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)  -  *Displays a navigation menu.*

---

- [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/):  -  *Core class used to implement an HTML list of nav menu items.*

  - [Walker::start_lvl](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_lvl/)  -  *Starts the list before the elements are added.*
  - [Walker::end_lvl](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/end_lvl/)  -  *Ends the list of after the elements are added.*
  - [Walker::start_el](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/)  -  *Starts the element output.*
  - [Walker::end_el](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/end_el/)  -  *Ends the element output, if needed.*

Comment: Hey, @benny-ben thanks for this but still the same problem I tried changing the properties to my menu_id and even header-menu. I still get the same error, its so strange to me why it is not working

Comment: @JoeyIreland **1)** What warnings/errors do you give in the browser console? **2)** Is [this](https://github.com/automattic/_s) the theme you're using? **3)** Are you sure you've loaded the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files with [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)/[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)?

Comment: it's not showing any :/ and I am positive I have loaded them

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented the menu in wrong way, that's why it's not working.

WordPress has provided a detailed documentation on creating menu. You have to go through that first.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/

After implementing that properly then go for walker class. I have not worked with bootstrap 3.3.7 but letting you know that bootstap 4x works fine, seems you have the walker class for version 3x.. you can use that.

Use below link for Bootstrap 4x:
https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Here is a tutorial :
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-a-bootstrap-navbar-into-a-wordpress-theme--wp-33410

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 
            'depth' => 1, 
            'container' => 'div', 
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 
            'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1', 
            'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav mr-auto', 
            'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback', 
            'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Followed that and still have the lines of code inside of nav

Comment: @JoeyIreland Then it seems something wrong with the header.php file, will you be able to add the header.php file to your question?

Comment: Yes i will do it now

Comment: @JoeyIreland you seems to have commented a php code improperly. Use this :wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 
            'depth' => 1, 
            'container' => 'div', 
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 
            'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1', 
            'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav mr-auto', 
            'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback', 
            'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() ) ); ?>

Comment: Hey, I have added that code and i am still getting the lines instead of the nav :/

Comment: @JoeyIreland is it same as answer that i have updated?

Comment: yes i believe so

Comment: @JoeyIreland try to add the menu without any nav walker and let me know how it goes.

Comment: As in just use HTML? or using WordPress menu, if i use WP it still gives the same error

Comment: @JoeyIreland wordpress menu. Follow  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/

Comment: Yes following that just gives me the same thing

Comment: https://imgur.com/1Is9sCQ

Comment: @JoeyIreland do you have <?php wp_head(); ?> in the header?

Comment: Yeah i think i do

Comment: No not in the header.php on the front page i do

Comment: @JoeyIreland comment out all the php function in the template expect the walker also let me know if the top wordpress bar is showing up.

Comment: Yes that is showing

Comment: @JoeyIreland whether the menu is working?

Comment: the menu is not

Comment: hmm sorry buddy i can't help. you have to start from the basic without any other functions in the file . hope you have added the header file and try adding the wp_head in the header.php